How to restart DMS jobs after Blue/Green deployment?
We have an AWS RDS PostgreSQL server running on PG 13.5. We plan to upgrade to 16.3 using Blue/Green deployment. We have a few AWS DMS jobs which created logical replication slots and are pushing data into Redshift. We have to stop the DMS jobs and drop the replication slots to carry out Blue/Green upgrade. If we complete the upgrade and then create the same replication slots in the Green environment, will the DMS jobs resume without any problem? I feel the jobs may search for specific LSNs, fail to find them and fail.
